# How do I fix an error returning "import "pytest" could not be resolved Pylance?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, importerror, pylance

I am new to coding so I'm not sure where to even start in correcting this. I've reached out to my teacher for help, but he hasn't gotten back to me and I really wanted to finish this assignment tonight so if anyone could help I would be forever grateful.

[image: code with error]

I followed the steps my teacher provided in order to install pytest on the command prompt, but when I try typing pytest --version it doesn't recognize pytest there either.

[image: command prompt with error]

I tried going to the Command Palette and selecting the Python Interpreter based on a reddit thread I found suggesting it and restarted VS Code, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could select your python interpreter in VSCode by shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** and choose the python interpreter which you installed the package in.

If it still not work, you could run command `pip install pytest` in the terminal to install the package in the current interpreter.